# Instead of show/hide details in jQuery datatables, can the details be displayed on another tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

We are using jQuery tabs and accordio menus in our app.

We are looking at the example contained on the link below:

http://www.chrisschnaars.org/2011/11/16/building-jquery-datatables-with-expandable-accordion-rows/

If you click the link, you see in the middle where it says `you can go **here**`

However, instead of clicking a plus sign (+) to expand the row to show details, is it possible to have a link on the first column and if a user clicks the link, details of the particular row opens up on another tab called details.

Is  this possible?

I have scoured the web but could not find any example of this.

Thanks alot in advance.

BTW: we will be setting bServerSide to true since we will be pointing to a php file.

Comment: when you click a row you have access to that row data... could simply make ajax call to get detail, and populate a tab with results

Comment: @charlietfl, sorry for late response.

Any example script?

Comment: here's a crude demo that gets property from row data and makes ajax request  http://plnkr.co/edit/LiZYJV0VYHw8OBEzvLJu?p=preview

Comment: @charlietfl, very nice effort. What we wanted though are 2 things. 1, the ID shoud be like a link so user can click on ID to open details page

2, if you clicks on any records, it should automatically open in the Details tab.

For instance, the row of records should be on the `Aenean lacinia` tab.

If user clicks on each ID, the the `Details` tab should automatically open up to display the details of the record you clicked. Is this possible?

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: feel free to modify demo and save a new fork. Not fully understanding description. Also not sure where `details` comes from. Perhaps by `new tab` you mean new browser tab? If so, all you need is set `target="_blank"` on link

Comment: check demo link again, I think i have better idea what you want

Comment: @charlietfl, if you look your original demo, there is a tab called `Aenean lacinia`. This tab is where rows of records are stored, starting with Id, Item, etc.

Then there is another tab on your demo called `Details`. When a user clicks on the ID link, it should automatically open the `Details` tab to display the detailed records associated with the ID user clicked on.

Hope it is clearer. If it is not possible, I can understand.

Thanks again.

Comment: please update demo yourself to reflect sample html and layout wanted. What you want is not likely difficult, I'm just not follwoing it exactly. Plenty of room in demo to write better explanation

Comment: @charlietfl,

I have updated the demo with the original code you had there before.

Now, if you take a look at the demo, you see `Aenean lacinia` tab, `Details` tab, and `Proin dolor` tab, Now, the `Aenean lacinia` tab contains row of records with ID, Item, details button.

Our hope is that the ID should be there as link instead of the details button.

Then if you click on any of IDs, the details should automatically open on the `Details` tab.

I pray that this is clearer.

Comment: where is link to your version?

Comment: @charlietfl, Oh sorry. I thought it was same link. Here it is:

http://plnkr.co/edit/7kGxA2ojfBDMzegJa0Tv?p=preview

Comment: looks identical to my first demo...no explanation or changes I can see. WIthout more clarification I am very unclear what you want

Comment: @charlietfl, OK thanks for all the help because I don't know how else to explain it. First, I said it was your first demo. Second, ALL we wanted was to make the ID a hyperlink so that when a user clicks on it, the detailed records automatically open in the `Details` tab and display the details of records associated with the ID you just clicked. If this is not clear, I don't know how else to explain it. Normally, when you click on a link, it opens a new window and displays the details of records. This time, we just want it to display in the tab called `Details`.

Comment: all I'm asking is to put explanation(s) in demo where I can see it in context of the html and not in tiny comment blocks like here

Comment: @charlietfl, Ok I will try it again now. Please give me a few minutes.

Comment: @charlietfl, please take a look at this demo. I don't think I did it quite detailed but I think it makes the point I have been trying to make.
http://plnkr.co/edit/7kGxA2ojfBDMzegJa0Tv?p=preview

Notice now that the ID on `Records` tab now has hyperlink.

Our hope is that each time a user clicks on any of the ID links, the detailed records asssociated with that ID will automatically open the `Details` tab and is displayed there.

Comment: try this http://plnkr.co/edit/gqLoGFtThwRffDiTrhQx?p=preview

Comment: @charlietfl, that's IT!!!! Thank you so muuch for your patience and incredible assistance. Thanks very, very much.

Please change it so I can give you your due credit.

Comment: actually surprised you couldn't adapt from very first button example...hope it works well for you

Comment: @charlietfl, there are additional changes I will have to make but this gives me the headstart I was looking for.